# Taylor expansion with random variables $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

In Einsteins theory of relativity the kinetic energy of an object is given by the following formula

$$E_k = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v}{c}^2}} - mc^2$$

where m is mass of the object at rest v iss volecity and c is speed of light.

where v is velocity and c is the speed of light.
Usinbg a first order taylor expansion of
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v}{c}^2}}$$

show that this reduces to $E_k = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$

I say is impossible because m is not anywhere in it so it can't possibly come out of nowhere to exist in the expansion reduction.

Comment: Expand $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ in $v$ *and then subtract 1 and multiply the result by $mc^2$*.

Comment: I have very little interest in just seeing an answer, I want to know why.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with random variables? Is $v$ coming from a Boltzmann distribution or something?

Comment: Thanks for quoting the full problem! You say that "m is not anywhere in it". Anywhere in what? Every equation with an $E_k$ on the left side has an $m$ on the right side, so there is no problem.

Comment: I just don't know which one is suppose to be the variable, or if all of them are.

Comment: What I am supose to expand has no m.

Comment: You're supposed to expand in $v$, the velocity of the object. The mass $m$ and the speed of light $c$ are constants. It's poorly explained; I see that now. :)

Comment: Doesn't the mass change as velocity changes?

Comment: It's important in these questions to distinguish between "rest mass" and "relativistic mass".  "Rest mass" is constant, regardless of speed, but "relativistic mass" changes with velocity.  In this case, $m$ refers to rest mass.

Comment: No, the mass is not a function of velocity. Once upon a time, there was a concept of "relativistic mass" that changed with velocity, but it was a conceptual dead-end and nobody uses it anymore. Either way, for the purposes of this problem, $m$ is definitely a constant. Your textbook has made this explicit by saying "where $m$ is mass of the object **at rest**".

Comment: "What I am supose to expand has no m." The will $m$ come from the full expression for $E_k$ of which the reciprocal square root thingy is a part. You're supposed to use that Taylor expansion to obtain one for $E_k$. What happens when you substitute the Taylor expansion for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ w.r.t. v in the expression for $E_k$?

Comment: Nothing useful as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

The first-order expansion of $f(z) = \frac1{\sqrt{1-z}}$ gives us
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{1-z}}\approx 1+\frac12 z
$$
Substitute $z=\frac{v^2}{c^2}$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\approx 1+\frac{1}2 \frac{v^2}{c^2}
$$
multiply by $mc^2$ to get
$$
\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\approx mc^2+\frac{mc^2}2 \frac{v^2}{c^2}
$$
Now, subtract the object's rest energy, and what do you get?

Comment: What is a rest energy?

Comment: that's just $mc^2$, where $m$ is the object's mass at rest.

Comment: How do I get a taylor excpansion without values for x?

Comment: By $x$, I assume you mean $z$. I've edited my question a little, and hopefully I've made it clearer.  We say that the first line is true for (for our purposes) any $z$.  We then substitute $z=v^2/c^2$ to get a new equation that holds no matter what $v$ and $c$ are.  Then we multiply by $mc^2$ to get another equation.  Does that make sense?

Comment: No, by definition a taylor series is multiplied ba na (x-a)  and evaluted at f(a) where is that?

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$. The center of our Taylor series is $0$, so for this series $a=0$.  To get the first two terms, we note that $f(0) = 1$, and $f'(0) = \frac12$.  So, we get $$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)(x-0) + \cdots = 1 + \frac12x+\cdots$$ There's your derivation.

Comment: I stop at the $(x-0)^1$ coefficient in order to get what is called a "first order Taylor expansion", which is what the question asks for

Comment: Why is the center 0? Also I still don't see where m comes from.

Comment: Why would I subtract the resting thing anyways?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10099/discussion-between-omnomnomnom-and-paul-the-pirate)

Answer (score 0):

as v<<<  c ( practically)

√1- v²/c²  →(1+ v²/2c² )

substitute this to the question we get   E=m v²/2

Comment: This is not "alternative", it is a Taylor expansion around the origin.

Comment: this is binomial expansion isn't it ?

Comment: "This"? What is "this"?

Comment: i have studied that for
(1+x)^n = 1+nx 
when x is nearly 0
in binomial expansions

Comment: That is not entirely wrong. Indeed, $$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\binom{\alpha}kx^k$$ converges when $|x|<1$. Here $\alpha$ can be any real number. The cases when $\alpha$ is not a positive integer yield infinite sums, while when $\alpha$ is a positive integer we get the usual binomial theorem from Newton's time.